# If I update my Revit model at BIM 360 i will lost issues previously registered?

Tags: revit-api, autodesk-bim360

everyone!

I'm using BIM 360 to register issues in my Revit model. It is possible to update my model in revit and keep the issues at BIM 360?

example: If i had a issue in a element and if i move this element on revit, the issue will keep linked to this element?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BIM 360 Issues are linked to a document and element, but also stores the camera view. If you update the model it should follow that, as per product features (this is not on the API).